# How to access uploaded json file google colab

Tags: python, json, google-colaboratory

I'm stuck trying to read the files in google colab, It should read the file as a simple JSON but I can't even do a `json.dumps(file)` without getting 100 of errors

Uploading the file:

```
import json 
import csv 
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()
```

Printing works, It shows the content of the file:

```
print(uploaded)
data = json.dumps(uploaded)
```

But I get `Object of type 'bytes' is not JSON serializable` when trying to do `json.dumps(uploaded)`

Shouldn't the file be read as `json` and not `bytes`? In some other cases, I tested it also read as `dictionary`

JSON file:

```
[
    {
        "type": "message",
        "subtype": "channel_join",
        "ts": "123",
        "user": "DWADAWD",
        "text": "<@DWADAWD> has joined the channel"
    },
    {
        "type": "message",
        "subtype": "channel_join",
        "ts": "123",
        "user": "DWADAWD",
        "text": "<@DWADAWD> has joined the channel"
    },
    {
        "text": "Let's chat",
        "user_profile": {
            "display_name": "XASD",
            "team": "TDF31231",
            "name": "XASD",
            "is_restricted": false,
            "is_ultra_restricted": false
        },
        "blocks": [
            {
                "type": "rich_text",
                "block_id": "2N1",
                "elements": [
                    {
                        "type": "rich_text_section",
                        "elements": [
                            {
                                "type": "text",
                                "text": "Let's chat"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: What do/don't you understand from that error message? Also, please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Comment: Why is the json file being read as `bytes` or sometimes as `dictionary`?

Comment: What do the contents of the file look like?

Comment: Can I send a screenshot now?

Comment: It's best to share the actual contents, and a **[mcve]**.

Comment: @AMC I updated my question and included the file content

Comment: What do `type(uploaded)` and `print(uploaded)` return?

Comment: `type(uploaded)` returns `dict` and `print(uploaded)` returns the content of the json as `{'test.json': b'[\n    {\n        "type": "message",\n        "subtype": "channel_join",\n`

Comment: Is that actually **just** the content of the JSON? (hint: look carefully)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you upload just 1 file. You can get the content from its `values()`

```
data = next(iter(uploaded.values()))
```

Then, you can convert json string to dict

```
d = json.loads(data.decode())
```

Here's an example [notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1qNrX53qAvd4wftoo-3_86JxsCUoWL9O_)

Answer (score 1):

JSON handles Unicode strings, not byte sequences. Try:

```
json.dumps(uploaded.decode("utf-8"))
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use *io* and *files*.

First, I import them (and pandas):

```
import io
import pandas as pd
from google.colab import files
```

Then, I use a file widget to upload the file:

```
uploaded = files.upload()
```

[image]

To load the data into a dataframe:

```
df = pd.read_json(io.StringIO(uploaded.get('file.json').decode('utf-8')))
```

The dataframe **df** has all json data.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is by uploading your json files to Colab and then copying their path as the filename.

Here's how it is done:

```
import io
import pandas as pd
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()
```

This is where you'd upload your files.

Now if you click on the following folder icon on the left side of your code on Colab, you should see your uploaded files.
[image]

Hover over the filename, click on the 3 dots next to it and click on 'copy path'.

[image]

After this, simply use this code by pasting the file path copied:

```
df = pd.read_json('file_path_copied')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
from google.colab import files
import json
import pandas as pd
import io

print('\x1b[1;31m'+'Please Upload File'+'\x1b[0m')
data = files.upload()
df = pd.read_json(io.BytesIO(data[list(data)[0]]))
```